# Hallar count de 2 tablas distintas con una llave

Tags: sql, join, count

Tengo 2 tablas, una de ventas y otra de cancelaciones, con los siguientes campos:

```
Ventas: 
FechaVenta, Producto

Cancelaciones:
FechaVenta, Producto, FechaBaja
```

Y necesito obtener lo siguiente:

```
Periodo     Productos   Ventas  Cancelaciones   Netas
Ene-2018    Plan 30     3557    2803            754
Feb-2018    Plan 70     3151    3454           -303
```

De momento con el query que uso obtengo valores erróneos.

Comment: Agrega lo que lleves al momento

Comment: Ademas agrega el tipo de gestor que es: MySQL, SQL, Oracle, etc

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [ask]. En su formato actual, tu _pregunta_ parece más una solicitud para que alguien realice tu tarea escolar o trabajo. Te recomiendo que la edites y la enfoques a alguna duda particular y no simplemente presentar una solicitud y esperar el trabajo hecho. Es buena idea que expliques qué es lo que has investigado/intentado y el problema que actualmente impide que logres el objetivo.

Comment: Adicional comento que edité tu pregunta para mejorar el formato de presentación de la misma, debieras aprender como hacerlo por ti mismo, el editor cuenta con algunos botones que te ayudan con el _markdown_, entre ellos hay un par que te proveen documentación.